# How do I download a file from S3 to an iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, amazon-s3

I am new to iPhone development.  I am developing an iPhone application which needs to open files stored on Amazon's S3 service.

How do I download a file from S3 to my iPhone application?  I have tried Amazon's SDK, but they don't seem to provide a means of downloading and saving a file.  How do I go about obtaining a file's URL from S3 and saving it in my application?

Comment: I'd use the AWS SDK for iOS - S3 is complicated by its nature - the code sample should help - https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-ios/tree/master/samples/awsBrowser

Comment: I tried that code only... They gave sample to get details about the file but they dint give samples to download or open files...

Comment: Quick search on forum shows posts asking about file downloading problems, so possible - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=69971&tstart=0

Comment: They are dealing uploading problem alone :( Not even spoke a single word regarding download :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always use the [ASIHttpRequest library](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/S3) to do this and it's quite simple, here's a sample code from their website:

```
NSString *secretAccessKey = @"my-secret-access-key";
NSString *accessKey = @"my-access-key";
NSString *bucket = @"my-bucket";
NSString *path = @"path/to/the/object";

ASIS3ObjectRequest *request = [ASIS3ObjectRequest requestWithBucket:bucket key:path];
[request setSecretAccessKey:secretAccessKey];
[request setAccessKey:accessKey];
[request startSynchronous];
if (![request error]) {
  NSData *data = [request responseData];
} else {
  NSLog(@"%@",[[request error] localizedDescription]);
}
```

You can't get easier than this :)

Comment: Ok i ll try this and let you know the result... Inbetween how to open the downloaded file??? For example how to open downloaded PDF file using viewer???

Comment: @iteeps - Viewing a PDF file is a separate question.  I've edited your original to keep it focused on the problems of downloading files from S3.  If you search around here, you'll find many examples of how to view PDF files, either in a UIWebView or using Quartz.

Comment: @Mauricio - Am getting error on this... Actually i ve tried one project seperately and then tried by creating an view controller in their demo project itself but both getting errors :( Error am getting is : "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIS3ObjectRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-ASIS3ObjectRequest in objectDownloadController.o
 Any Idea???

Comment: @Maurício Linhares I have facing error like "The specified key does not exist." so plz let me know what is the issue?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have the luxury of simplicity using ASI, and/or are stuck with AWSiOS SDK, it's not a lot different:

```
/* borrowed from Maurício Linhares's answer */
NSString *secretAccessKey = @"my-secret-access-key";
NSString *accessKey = @"my-access-key";
NSString *bucket = @"my-bucket";
NSString *path = @"path/to/the/object";
/********************************************/

AmazonCredentials *credentials = [[AmazonCredentials alloc] initWithAccessKey: accessKey withSecretKey: secretAccessKey];
AmazonS3Client *connection = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithCredentials: credentials];

S3GetObjectRequest *downloadRequest = [[[S3GetObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:path withBucket: bucket] autorelease];
[downloadRequest setDelegate: self]; /* only needed for delegate (see below) */
S3GetObjectResponse *downloadResponse = [self.awsConnection getObject: downloadRequest];
```

Then you can look at `downloadResponse.body` and `downloadResponse.httpStatusCode`, preferable in a delegate:

```
-(void)request: (S3Request *)request didCompleteWithResponse: (S3Response *) response {
    NSLog(@"Download finished (%d)",response.httpStatusCode);
    /* do something with response.body and response.httpStatusCode */
    /* if you have multiple requests, you can check request arg */
}
```