# Connecting to S3 Using AWS SDK v2 (iOS)

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've been looking around and found no recent answer for a problem I'm having in uploading and downloading images from an iPhone application.

I'm using AWS SDK v2 and from what I have read and seen from sample S3 transfer codes, I need to start first using AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider.

```
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider
                                                          credentialsWithRegionType:AWSRegionAPNortheast1
                                                          accountId:AWSAccountID
                                                          identityPoolId:CognitoPoolID
                                                          unauthRoleArn:CognitoRoleUnauth
                                                      authRoleArn:nil];
```

But the only information I have are: Access Key, Secret, Bucket name, and target directory

Related link I read is [How do I download a file from S3 to an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829381/how-do-i-download-a-file-from-s3-to-an-iphone-application)

But the code cannot compile even with the AWS SDK framework, and related frameworks are installed in the project.

How can this be done using only the AWS SDK v2?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you follow the README and run the [S3TransferManager sample app](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/S3TransferManager-Sample). In the [Amazon Cognito console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cognito/), you can get the information you need to instantiate the credentials provider.

Also, currently [Amazon Cognito Identity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#cognito_identity_region) is available in `AWSRegionUSEast1` only.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll check that link. And if its only available at AWSRegionUSEast1 only, maybe we'll try to use the REST API.

Comment: Amazon Cognito is only available in `AWSRegionUSEast1`, but Amazon S3 is available in [many regions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region). The regions of these two services don't have to be the same.

Comment: Now US East (N. Virginia), EU (Ireland), and Asia Pacific (Tokyo) regions https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/09/amazon-cognito-is-now-available-in-the-asia-pacific-tokyo-region/

Answer (score 14):

You can also scrap using Cognito and use the Access Key/Secret:

```
AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [AWSStaticCredentialsProvider credentialsWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY_ID secretKey:SECRET_KEY];
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [AWSServiceConfiguration configurationWithRegion:AWSRegionUSWest2
                                                                      credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
```

Make sure you use the region your bucket is actually in.

Comment: those methods look deprecated

Comment: Amazon doesn't recommend them for production but instead pushes one to AWSCognito http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSStaticCredentialsProvider.html

Answer (score 8):

For your convenience, I left the version in Swift

```
let credentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey:"YOUR_ACCESS_KEY", secretKey: "YOUR_SECRET_KEY")
let defaultServiceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.EUWest1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
defaultServiceConfiguration.maxRetryCount = 5
AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = defaultServiceConfiguration
let defaultS3 = AWSS3.defaultS3()
```

......